# Automatic binding for boost::thread in C++?

Tags: c++, boost

When doing:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int number = 4;
boost::thread workerThread(&Method, number, vec)

given a method:
template<typename T>
void Method(int n, std::vector<T> & vec)
{
    //does stuff
}
```

Why do I have to manually do:

```
boost::thread workerThread(&Method, number, boost::ref(vec))?
```

Why does it not automatically pass it by reference?

Edit:: so would it be possible theoretically for boost::thread to do some macro-meta-programming to adjust this since C++ has nothing in the way of built in reflection/introspection.

So is a major part of boost / C++ in general passing meta-information around?

Comment: If the inverse convention were chosen, then you'd need a special wrapper to mean 'make you own copy of my value', e.g. `boost::thread t(&f, val(arg));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `boost::thread` object cannot determine the signature of `Method`.

He only knows the types of the *arguments being passed in* and will forward them to the provided function. If the types don't match you get a nice complicated error message at the place where `boost::thread` attempts to call the function.

When looking at the types of the arguments, it is impossible to differ between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value as they *look the same* from the caller's side. Or from a more formal perspective: In template argument deduction `T&` will decay to `T`.

Only by providing the explicit `boost::ref` on the caller's side `boost::thread` will be able to correctly identify the type as a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the workerThread might be trying to deduce the types in signaure of Method , which it cant deduce from &Method, itself.